# Binding function to current item in React

Tags: reactjs, function, find, bind

I want to display button to add a book if the book doesn't exists in usersBooks array, I think the function works well but binding causes problem:

```
doesExistInUsersBooks = (title) => {
        if(this.props.userBooks.find(b => b.title == title)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm using it this way: `!this.doesExistInUserBooks.bind(this, title) && <Button ... />`

Comment: Bind it in the constructor: `this.doesExistInUserBooks = this.doesExistInUserBooks.bind(this)` and after you doesn't need to bind it anymore

Answer (score 0):

You are using ES6 auto-binding when you have declared your function. That is why do not need binding. You should try to change your code to this:

!doesExistInUserBooks(title)

Comment: I know that, I use es6, but still needed to bind the function which creates a network request, before that it had been creating 10 request, for each item in array..

Answer (score 0):

you need call the func:

`this.doesExistInUsersBooks.bind(this, title)() && <Button ... />`

check it there, its working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xedawq?embed=1&file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is either declare your function such a way:

```
doesExistInUsersBooks(title){
// your code
}
```

or as Serdar suggested use it like:

```
!doesExistInUserBooks(title)
```